# How do I draw transparent DirectX content in a transparent window?

Tags: c#, windows, directx, transparent, direct3d

I want to draw DirectX content so that it appears to be floating over top of the desktop and any other applications that are running. I also need to be able to make the directx content semi-transparent, so other things show through. Is there a way of doing this?

I am using Managed DX with C#.

Comment: Aren't layered windows an option?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution which works on Vista, starting from the link provided by OregonGhost. This is the basic process, in C# syntax. This code is in a class inheriting from Form. It doesn't seem to work if in a UserControl:

```
//this will allow you to import the necessary functions from the .dll
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

//this imports the function used to extend the transparent window border.
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
static extern void DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hWnd, ref Margins pMargins);

//this is used to specify the boundaries of the transparent area
internal struct Margins {
    public int Left, Right, Top, Bottom;
}
private Margins marg;

//Do this every time the form is resized. It causes the window to be made transparent.
marg.Left = 0;
marg.Top = 0;
marg.Right = this.Width;
marg.Bottom = this.Height;
DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(this.Handle, ref marg);

//This initializes the DirectX device. It needs to be done once.
//The alpha channel in the backbuffer is critical.
PresentParameters presentParameters = new PresentParameters();
presentParameters.Windowed = true;
presentParameters.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
presentParameters.BackBufferFormat = Format.A8R8G8B8;

Device device = new Device(0, DeviceType.Hardware, this.Handle,
CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProcessing, presentParameters);

//the OnPaint functions maked the background transparent by drawing black on it.
//For whatever reason this results in transparency.
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    // black brush for Alpha transparency
    SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    g.FillRectangle(blackBrush, 0, 0, Width, Height);
    blackBrush.Dispose();

    //call your DirectX rendering function here
}

//this is the dx rendering function. The Argb clearing function is important,
//as it makes the directx background transparent.
protected void dxrendering() {
    device.Clear(ClearFlags.Target, Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);

    device.BeginScene();
    //draw stuff here.
    device.EndScene();
    device.Present();
}
```

Lastly, a Form with default setting will have a glassy looking partially transparent background. Set the FormBorderStyle to "none" and it will be 100% transparent with only your content floating above everything.

Answer (score 6):

You can either use DirectComposition, LayeredWindows, DesktopWindowManager or WPF. All methods come with their advantages and disadvantages:

-DirectComposition is the most efficient one, but needs Windows 8 and is limited to 60Hz.

-LayeredWindows are tricky to get working with D3D via Direct2D-interop using DXGI.

-WPF is relatively easy to use via D3DImage, but is also limited to 60Hz and DX9 and no MSAA. Interops to higher DX-Versions via DXGI are possible, also MSAA can be used when the MSAA-Rendertarget is resolved to the native nonMSAA surface.

-DesktopWindowManager is great for high performance available since Windows Vista, but DirectX-Versions seem to be limited by the Version the DWM uses (still DX9 on Vista). Workarounds for higher DX-Versions should be possible via DXGI where available.

If you don't need per pixel aplha, you can also use the opacity-value of a semi-transparent form.

Or you use the native Win32 method for the Window global alpha (Remember a alpha of 0 will not catch the mouse input):

```
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
COLORREF color = 0;
BYTE alpha = 128;
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, color, alpha, LWA_ALPHA);
```

I have been able to use all of the described techniques with C# and SharpDX, but in case of DirectComposition, LayeredWindows and native Win32 a little C++-Wrappercode was needed. For starters I would suggest to go via WPF.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that will be hard without using the Desktop Window Manager, i.e. if you want to support Windows XP. With the DWM, it seems to be [rather easy](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/umvistad3d.aspx) though.

If speed is not an issue, you may get away with rendering to a surface and then copying the rendered image to a layered window. Don't expect that to be fast though.

Comment: A pain that only works with dx9, since DWM in Vista is dx9. Windows 7 will use dx10, so that will be nice.

Answer (score 1):

[WPF](http://learnwpf.com/) is also another option.

> Developed by Microsoft, the Windows Presentation Foundation (or WPF) is a computer-software graphical subsystem for rendering user interfaces in Windows-based applications.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Notice how this was answered nearly 4 years ago, during the beta? Questions and answers back then were experimental. This is certainly not a brilliant answer, but it _is_ an answer and a viable one at that. The link is valid as is the content.