# Only achieving partial transparency (winforms/Directx)

Tags: c#, .net, directx

I followed these instructions: [How do I draw transparent DirectX content in a transparent window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148275/how-do-i-draw-transparent-directx-content-in-a-transparent-window), and then changed the FormBorderStyle to "none" as instructed, but this results in only a partial transparency, not full, is there something I may be missing? I am using MS VS 2010.

Comment: Have you considered using WPF instead? :-)

Comment: Yes, I know this is achievable with winforms though as has been documented

Comment: What do you mean by partial transparency? Is it just a bit transparent? Or is a part of it fully transparent and the rest is visible?

Comment: as in frosted glass looking, all over

Comment: Since that description uses DWM, that's what it has to do. Look at this screenshot for example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17727/Unmanaged-Vista-Power

Comment: ...thanks, however, in the text beneath the screenshot there is discussion about removing it, as in it doesn't have to do it, still working it out.

Comment: @user1166981 - You never told us the reason you are not using WPF for this.  it is much easier in WPF then it is in WinForms.

Comment: I have a good reason for it, and I am one line of code away from solving this I feel. In truth I want to make a fully transparant full screen overlay with directx inside but I only have the code to do it for winforms and not the skill to reproduce it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077236/transparent-window-layer-that-is-click-through-and-always-stays-on-top - another ongoing problem.